# How docker detects which changes should be saved and which not?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I know that when we stop docker our changes are lost. There are many answers how to prevent this - **commit** each time. Idea is that **when docker runs it will spin up a fresh container** based on the image. On the other hand container persists **some data** after it exists unless you start using **--rm**.

Just to simplify:

- If you run **apt-get install vim**, you must **commit** to save the change
- **BUT** If you change **nginx.conf** or upload **new** file to HDFS, you **do not lose** the data.

**So, just curious**:
How docker knows **what to save and what not**? Ex: At the end of **apt-get-install** we have **new files** in the system. **The same is when** I upload new file. for the container/image **there is NO difference** , Right?  Just **I/O modification.** So how docker know which modification should be saved when we stop the image?

Answer (score 2):

The basic rules here:

1. Anything you explicitly store outside the container — a database, S3 — will outlive the container.
2. If you attach a volume to the container *when you create the container* using a `docker run -v` option or a Docker Compose `volumes:` option, any data written to that directory outlives the container.  (If it’s a named volume, it lasts until you `docker volume rm` it.)
3. Anything else in the container filesystem is lost as soon as you `docker rm` the container.

If you need things like your application source code or a helper tool installed in an image, write a `Dockerfile` to describe how to build the image and run `docker build`.  Check the `Dockerfile` into source control alongside your application.

The general theory of working with Docker is that you always start from a clean slate.  When you `docker build` an image, you start from a base image and install your application into it; you never try to upgrade an installed application.  Similarly, when you `docker run` a container, you start from a fresh copy of its image.

So the clearest answer to the question you ask is really, if you consistently `docker rm` a container when you stop it, when you `docker run` a new container, it will have the base image plus the content from the mounted volumes.  Docker will never automatically persist anything outside of this.

You should *never* run `docker commit`: this leads to magic images that can’t be recreated later (in six months when you discover a critical security issue that risks taking your site down).  Similarly, you should never install software in a running container, because it will be lost as soon as the container exits; add it to your `Dockerfile` and rebuild.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. How can I find out what is outside the container and what is not? For example I have Hortonworks Hadoop in docker. Looks only OS and Hadoop service are in the container. But when I modify system settings, upload files - they are out of the container? How should be nginix configuration outside the container? I just don't understand. When I stop docker I still have the modified configuration.

Comment: Generally for things like an nginx configuration, a good way to deal with them is to have them as plain files on your host, and inject them with `docker run -v` when you start the containers.

Comment: The strange is that - when I stop container and start once again, it has modified nginx config. It should be clean/new, should not it?

Comment: If you didn’t `docker rm` the container, when you `docker start` again it will have the same filesystem.

Comment: Final question: If I install vim and If I didn't docker rm, when I start docker, will I have vim once again?

Comment: By “install vim”, you mean “I edited my `Dockerfile` and re-ran `docker build`”, yes?  In which case you must `docker rm` the container to get it to restart with the new image.  (If you did it in a `docker exec` shell, it will “last” until you `docker rm` the container, and you will be forced to eventually.)

Comment: No. Just apt-get install vim via  the terminal. Everything looks clear but that's why I'm confused: If I run "apt-get install" in the terminal (without docker rm), this change is lost. but the same time all the updated configuration remains updated (still without docker rm). So just don't understand how docker can distinguish what to persist and what not (everything looks to be inside the container).

Answer (score 0):

For any Container working with the Docker platform by default all the data generated is temporary and all the file generation or data generation is temporary and no data will persist if you have not mounted the filesystem part of if you have not attached volumes to the container.

IF you are finding that the nginx.conf is getting reused even after changes i would suggest try to find what directories are you trying to mount or mapped to the docker volumes. 
The configurations for nginx which reside at /etc/nginx/conf.d/* and you might be mapping the volume with this directory. So if you make any changes in a working container and then remove the container the data will still persist as the data gets written to the writable layer. If the new container which you deploy later with the same volume mapping you will find all the changes you had initially done in the previous case are reflected in the newer container as well.